# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [abc] and [Testing] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/welcome] which is not permitted

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I want to build a simple Servlet in Java with Eclipse and Apache TomCat 7.

So I have download Tomcat 7.0 on my local pc, extract under c:\ .

I have created a simple Dinamyc web project, then I have add one simple Servlet like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Testing
 */
@WebServlet("/welcome")
public class Testing implements Servlet {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public Testing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#getServletConfig()
     */
    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#getServletInfo()
     */
    public String getServletInfo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null; 
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
     */
    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Testing</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

But if I try to run application on the server I have this error:

```
gen 22, 2016 9:21:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFORMAZIONI: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_66/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\TomcatA\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin;D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Samsung\AllShare Framework DMS\1.3.23\;C:\Program Files\Samsung\AllShare Framework DMS\1.3.23\64bit\;C:\Python27;c:\Python27\Scripts;C:\SDKfolder\naoqi-sdk\include;C:\SDKfolder;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\michele.castriotta\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;D:\eclipse\eclipse_mars;;.
gen 22, 2016 9:21:26 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TestServlet' did not find a matching property.
gen 22, 2016 9:21:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
gen 22, 2016 9:21:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
gen 22, 2016 9:21:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAZIONI: Initialization processed in 1586 ms
gen 22, 2016 9:21:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting service Catalina
gen 22, 2016 9:21:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
gen 22, 2016 9:21:28 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFORMAZIONI: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [231] milliseconds.
gen 22, 2016 9:21:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TestServlet]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TestServlet]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [abc] and [Testing] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/welcome] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2466)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2148)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJndi(ContextConfig.java:2071)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1978)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1300)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

gen 22, 2016 9:21:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

gen 22, 2016 9:21:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

gen 22, 2016 9:21:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMAZIONI: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
gen 22, 2016 9:21:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMAZIONI: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
gen 22, 2016 9:21:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Stopping service Catalina
gen 22, 2016 9:21:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMAZIONI: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
gen 22, 2016 9:21:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMAZIONI: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Comment: All needed information is provided in your log. What don't you understand?

Comment: "The servlets named [abc] and [Testing] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/welcome] which is not permitted", makes sense?

Comment: Ok but how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

When you want map servlet to some path, you should point the servlet in web.xml **OR** in servlet by annotation `@WebServlet`. So currently you have to remove annotation from servlet or `<servlet-mapping>` block in web.xml